# What's the significance of the second arguement in update() in Observer interface method

Tags: java, design-patterns

While studying the Observer Pattern
The Observer interface has the update method :

```
public void update(Observable obs, Object obj)
```

The first parameter is the observer that issued the update() method , but I fail to understand the second parameter Object obj . The Oracle documentation states it as :

> arg - an argument passed to the notifyObservers method.

If I try to print it , java throws NPE, if it's null what's the use of it?

Comment: It's called with what is passed to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers%28java.lang.Object%29. But really, these Observable/Observer classes are a badly designed relic from the early days of Java, that aren't used by anyone. You'd better forget about their existence.

Comment: Oh, if they're deprecated and archaic , can you suggest me any newer and better methods to accomplish the same task?

Comment: Define an interface (like FooBarListener), with callback method(s) called when your FooBar wants to notify of changes. Add methods addFooBarListener() and removeFooBarListener() to your FooBar class. Store the listeners in a list. Iterator on the list and call the callback methods when needed. Or use one of the existing JavaBean mechanisms if they fit, like PropertyChangeListener/PropertyChangeSupport. Hard to give a best answer without knowing the use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will first answer your query - the `Object` argument in the `update` call is the object you pass to the  `notifyObservers()` method. Note that `notifyObservers()` also has an overload `notifyObservers(Object arg)` This `arg` is what is passed as the second parameter to the `update` method.

Refer to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/observable_notifyobservers_object.htm) link for an example.

In your case you must be calling the `notifyObservers()` overload - which may default to a null object being passed to the `update` method.

That said - the Observable pattern in Java is an archaic brittle concept as **JB Nizet** commented. in terms of alternatives there is an [article](http://www.lordofthejars.com/2011/10/una-terra-promessa-un-mondo-diverso.html) that would use Spring Events to implement an Observer pattern.

It is also not too difficult to implement your own. Check out this  [example](http://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Every registered listener will be notified and receive that object. It's like an event in the callback of a javascript onClick. If you want to give some info to the listeners from update(), that object gives you the means.

Answer (score 0):

The important point to note is that the two argument method actually represents two styles of information passing to the Observer.
An `Observable` has two methods for notifications - either `notifyObservers()` or `notifyObservers(Object args)` - in the latter method the argument is an 
**arbitrary** data object passed. So if an application wants to support ***pushing*** data, then it will call the methods with argument and pass the data. However if this 
object passed is null then it means that the Observer has to ***pull*** interesting data ( whose change caused notification) from the Observable object itself.

The whole idea behind this design is that the Observable (subject) has state which is of interest to Observers. Also apart from state it has methods to add / remove / notify. So an application (external client) would have a Observable reference using which it will call appropriate methods to add/remove Observer objects for that particular Observable. Using this design each Observable can have a seperate list of Observers. Only thing Observable knows about Observers is that it has a list of interested Observers. A new Observer can be added at any time and also you don't need to modify Observable to add new types of Observer objects, you just need the class to implement Observer.